# Passing value to progress bar dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, updating

I want the progress bar to update after onclick function (func()). I need to update the this.progressBarValue dynamically I think, just its not working.

```js
var neededDonationValue = 150;
var maxDonationValue = 600;
var progressBarValue = 450;

document.getElementById("donationGoal").innerHTML = "$" + this.neededDonationValue + " needed to complete funding";
document.getElementById("donation-progress").value = this.progressBarValue;

function func() {
  this.donationValue = document.getElementById("donation-progress");
  this.donationValue.value = document.getElementById("donation-input").value;

  this.newDonationValue = this.donationValue.value + this.progressBarValue;
  this.newDonationNeededValue = maxDonationValue - this.newDonationValue;

  console.log(this.newDonationValue);
  console.log(this.donationValue.value);
  document.getElementById("donationGoal").innerHTML = "$" + this.newDonationNeededValue + " needed to complete funding";
  if (this.donationValue.value == 0) {
    document.getElementById("donationGoal").innerHTML = "Please enter an amount to continue";
    document.getElementById("donation-progress").value = this.progressBarValue;
  }
  if (this.newDonationValue >= 600) {
    document.getElementById("time-left").innerHTML = "We have reached our goal ";
    document.getElementById("donationGoal").innerHTML = "$ 0 needed to complete funding";
    document.getElementById("donation-input").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

I am trying to pass on a new value to my progress bar, but it is not working.